# What is meant by the asterisk at http://inedomedia.com/stackoverflow.aspx

Tags: discussion, advertising

At http://inedomedia.com/stackoverflow.aspx there is a subheading which states: "4,026,489 developers are waiting for you *".

The asterisk implies there is a proviso attached to the statement. Is there?

Edit: Ya know, that asterisk left me so unfulfilled. It was like looking at waffles and not being allowed to eat em or ponies and not being able to *.

I'm glad I asked the question. meta meets all my waffle and pony needs.

Comment: The only ponies here are owned by TheTXI, waffles are scarce because everybody wants them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not to spoil the fun, but 4,026,489 refers to the "absolute unique visitors" that Google Analytics reported for July 2009. There *should* be something to the effect of...

> *Google Analytics, June 2009

... or something like that. What could be fun is a JavaScript-based counter like the GMail storage counter thing.

Comment: @Alex: You were being a buzzkill, so I fixed it for you.

Comment: @Eric: That got flagged for moderator attention, so I fixed it back. ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 19):

That asterisk is a regex symbol, allowing you to change the quote to:

"4,026,489 developers are waiting for you **to make ussome damn waffles**".

"4,026,489 developers are waiting for you **to ask a duplicate question**".

"4,026,489 developers are waiting for you **and we work for peanuts and alfalfa**".

"4,026,489 developers are waiting for you **and not doing their real job**".

"4,026,489 developers are waiting for you **and we're not wearing any clothes**".

"4,026,489 developers are waiting for you **to not RTFM**".

"4,026,489 developers are waiting for you **to give them ideas for a [TheDailyWTF.com](http://thedailywtf.com) submission**".

"4,026,489 developers are waiting for you **to feed the great Jon Skeet answering machine**".

Comment: +1 Awesome. Love it. Shoulda thought of it.

Comment: -1 for improper reference to the Kleene star when globbing was meant.

Comment: @Eric: -1 for not being the Eric I know and love.

Comment: `Namespace conflict`!

Comment: There are many pretenders to the throne.

Comment: @Eric: YOU ARE A LIAR AND A THIEF. @TXI: +1 because I *love* waffles!

Comment: http://www.ericoverflow.com

Comment: ponyoverflow? ***duck*** and ***cover***

Comment: @Diago: Can you do something about this imposter? He's clearly not an Eric because he blew right past the waffles. No self-respecting Eric ignores waffles.

Comment: Unfortunately he has a few ponies over me.... But then again we can never know with an imposter. However I do offer free waffles?

Comment: You offer free waffles?! SOLD.

Comment: Wouldn't that be .*? (runs)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I will not allow you to ruin this for me.

Answer (score 10):

Doesn't an asterisk on any number used anywhere in advertising anywhere in the world mean the same thing anyway? I guess they just wanted to save space and electricty by omitting it, but here is the standard disclaimer:

> "This number may or may not be accurate, it may or may not be based on scientific data, it may or may not be gathered through survery and those surveys may or may not be done with a statistically meaninungful audience. Furthermore, the number may or may not be based on estimates, predictions, research, dreams and/or pure chance. Additionally the number may or may not be created using dice, geiger counters, random number generators, cake, waffles, ponies and cheese. We may or may not take any responsibility in the correctness of these numbers and should you have any doubts regarding the validity of them, you are free to contact our lawyers who may or may not ruin you. No animals and babies were harmed in the creation of this number, apart from the animals and babies that were. All rights reserved, this explanation is intended solely for the use of the individual or entity to whom they are addressed. This message contains confidential information and is intended only for the individual named and every violation of the end user license agreement (EULA) contained within this notice may or may not be punished by law, god or your mom."

Comment: Hey, those are special number generators, mister!

Comment: +1 for mentioning both waffles and ponies. But you did forgot our vamparian friends. Bad on you.

Comment: 74 percent of statistics are made up...

Comment: -1: Should be an unreadably small typeface.

Comment: @grenade you *probably* mean  74.25% :)

Comment: In my head I hear the Micro Machines guy reading this to me.

Answer (score 2):

The proviso is dependent on how many registered users there are on SO. There is an estimated 4 million developers world wide in this case, and not all of them are on SO yet.

However the potential is there that you will have access to that many developers at some point.

Answer (score 2):

*4,026,489* in hex is *0x3D7079*, which stands for *=py* in ASCII.

There definitely is a hidden message here. I just don't get it.

Comment: Clearly a message from the Python Cabal.  The same folks who keep sabotaging the release of Perl 6, in league with the GOP and the Illuminati.

Comment: It will all be explained in Dan Brown's next book.

Answer (score 1):

They might be waiting for someone else.